# Prevent URL-encoding of characters in link in MediaWiki

Tags: url, escaping, mediawiki

I.e.: **How to suppress substitution/replacement of characters with its html entities in a MediaWiki link?**

I need to insert a link looking like this, pipes (`|`) included, into a MediaWiki article:

```
http://www.somesite.asdf/#|param1|param2|param3
```

The target site does not accept `%7C` or `&#124;` as pipe-substitutes in its URL. Ergo, the following URLs are invalid:

```
http://www.somesite.asdf/#%7Cparam1%7Cparam2%7Cparam3
http://www.somesite.asdf/#&#124;param1&#124;param2&#124;param3
```

---

When I type the link into the MediaWiki-article like:

```
http://www.somesite.asdf/#|param1|param2|param3
```

... it results in a link pointing to:

```
http://www.somesite.asdf/#%7Cparam1%7Cparam2%7Cparam3
```

, which is not valid.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a valid URI; per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2), an URI consists of the characters `ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~" / ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@" / "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="`; everything else must be percent-encoded. MediaWiki automatically corrects invalid URLs (as would any other CMS, probably), so if this wiki is owned by someone else, you are out of luck. If it is yours, you can use some method to avoid the built-in HTML processing (e. g. enable the `<html>` tag); make sure you know what you are doing, this usually has security consequences.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. It's unbelievable - the target site is an official large-scale site, and it demands un-encoded pipes in its "fragment"-part (after `#`) of its URL. The wiki is mine, though, so workarounds _there_ are on the table. I just hoped there would be some way (i.e. an escape character) to suppress url-encoding of a link within the wiki-article without modifying/reconfiguring the MediaWiki-framework. It makes sense, however, that it's not immediately possible to create invalid links - so MediaWiki is not to blame.