# Turn off html processing in mediawiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, html-encode

I want to turn off the built in html processing of links in mediawiki. For example, I want to edit the Sidebar (MediaWiki:Sidebar) by adding a link with question marks and equal signs (i.e. `Special:CustomNeed?page_title=Name+with+spaces`), but the processing breaks the link to the following: `Special:CustomNeed%3Fpage_title%3DName%2Bwith%2Bspaces`. This way, the link doesn't work.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653058/prevent-url-encoding-of-characters-in-link-in-mediawiki), I thought there is a way to turn the processing off, however, I have no clue **how**. Do I have to add/edit something in the `LocalSettings.php`?

Comment: The question you link to is about a differend issue. Somethink like `https://example.com/foo|bar` is an invalid URL, that is turned into a valid URL by percent-encoding to `https://example.com/foo%7Cbar`. Most software will do this automatically. If eample.com hates web standards and interprets `|` and `%7C` differently, you are out of your luck. (...)

Comment: `?`, `=` and `+` are, on the other hand, entirely valid characters in an URL an MediaWiki will not encode them when it encounters them while expecting an URL. It will encode them when expecting a page name though, to suppress the special meaning they have in URLs. `https://my.site/wiki/a%3Fb` is a link to the `a?b` article, `https://my.site/wiki/a?b` is a link to the `a` article with an extra [parameter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php). You probably want the first when you enter `[[a?b]]` so MediaWiki encodes it for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, mediawikia (the special pages) can't deal with the converted links. But the accepted answer was exactly what I needed and helped

Comment: Well, `Special:CustomNeed%3Fpage_title%3DName%2Bwith%2Bspaces` is a link to the special page called `CustomNeed?page_title=Name+Bwith+spaces` which of course does not exist. You want a link to the `CustomNeed` special page, with the `page_title` parameter taking the value `Name+with+spaces`. Those are different things and since most normal humans are not aware of this difference, MediaWiki tries to guess which one you mean. If you enter a link without some prefix that would make it clear it's a link (e.g. `http://`, `https://`, `//`) it will guess wrong.

Comment: I don't doubt the correctness of your comment, but luckily, the accepted answer helps me bypass these shenaningans of mediawiki sidebar convertion. Nevertheless, thank you for your explanations ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specify query parameters for internal links so use full URLs instead: `http://example.com/wiki/Special:CustomNeed?page_title=Name+with+spaces`

See [Manual:Interface/Sidebar](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Sidebar) for details.

Comment: Not the most elegant way, but this does the trick! Is it possible to alter the link according to the page title? so instead of `Name+with+spaces` I'd add the title of the current page?

Comment: I just found out myself, {{FULLPAGENAME}} delivers the wanted result :)

Comment: A small improvement is to use, in place of the raw link: {{fullurl:Special:CustomNeed|action_title={{FULLPAGENAME}}}}

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting `$wgRawHtml = true;` in `LocalSettings.php`:

Then, you will be able to add your html links (or any code you wan't) within `<html></html>` tags.

Please keep in mind that it can be dangerous if your wiki is public, because people can insert any javascript code they want there.

Read more [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml)

Comment: `MediaWiki:Sidebar` is different, it's not parsed the way other pages/messages are.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The answer of Max is fitting my question more, but this is good to know as well.